# tooltip error only when highstock's point num > 10, why?

Tags: tooltip, highcharts

I write a new "pointFormatter" function to show the gap between 2 points, such as [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dodouwang/a9eytyqx/1/), but when I move the mouse to the first point "7.Jan", the tooltip doesn't show correctly, and I saw errorlog in console as "TypeError: this.series.data[preIndex] is undefined"

But, when I change the timeRange to "all", then the moving mouse to the first point doesn't cause any error any more, and when I change the timeRange back to "1w", it is OK also.

What is more, if I change the point num from 10 to 9 by deleting the last point, then the error doesn't occur any more.

Why? which thing caused this error?

```
$(function() {
var chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({

    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container'
    },
    rangeSelector: {                                                                                                                                                                                 
           allButtonsEnabled: true,                                                                                                                                                                     
           buttons: [{type: 'week',count: 1,text: '1w'},                                                                                                                                              

                     {type: 'all',text: 'all'}                                                                                                                                                         
           ],                                                                                                                                                                                           
           selected: 0                                                                                                                                                                                  
   }, 
   series: [{
        name: 'USD',
        data: [
            [0,null],
          [86400000,null],
          [86400000*2,null],
          [86400000*3,null],
          [86400000*4,null],
          [86400000*5,null],
          [86400000*6,3],
          [86400000*7,4],
          [86400000*8,6],
         [86400000*9,8],
        ]
    }],
    plotOptions: {                                                                                                                                                                                   
           line: {                                                                                                                                                                                      
               step: 'left',                                                                                                                                                                            
               connectNulls: true,                                                                                                                                                                      
               tooltip: {                                                                                                                                                                               
                   pointFormatter: function () {                                                                                                                                                        
                       var preIndex = this.index - 1;                                                                                                                                                   
                       while (preIndex >= 0 && this.series.data[preIndex].y == null) {                                                                                                                  
                           preIndex--;                                                                                                                                                                  
                       }                                                                                                                                                                                

                       if (preIndex < 0) {                                                                                                                                                              
                           return '<span style="color:' + this.series.color + '">\u25CF</span>' + this.series.name + ': <b>' + this.y + '</b><br/>';                                                  
                       } else {                                                                                                                                                                         
                           var prePoint = this.series.data[preIndex];                                                                                                                                   
                           var prePointY = prePoint.y;                                                                                                                                                  
                           var prePointX = prePoint.x;                                                                                                                                                  

                           var day = (this.x - prePointX) / 86400 / 1000;                                                                                                                               
                           var add = this.y - prePointY                                                                                                                                                 

                           add_str = '(' + add + ')';                                                                                                                                                   

                           return '<span style="color:' + this.series.color + '">\u25CF</span>' + this.series.name + ': <b>' + this.y + '</b> ' + add_str + '<br/>';                        
                       }                                                                                                                                                                                
                   }                                                                                                                                                                                    
               }                                                                                                                                                                                        
           }                                                                                                                                                                                            
    },                       
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Highstock has data grouping feature - more information [here](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/advanced-chart-features/data-grouping).

This feature can change the series.data array. Instead you can use series.options.data (original data from the options) or disable dataGrouping.

```
  plotOptions: {
    line: {
      dataGrouping: {enabled: false},
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/6mpt8xv2/